# VS 2010/SQLServer 2005 debugging hangs

Tags: sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2010, sqlclr

When attempt to debug a SQL CLR Function the debugger hangs.
Using VS2010 and SQL 2005.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem appear to be the conflict of Framework, VS2010 uses Framework 4.0 by default.
Following config file(sqlservr.exe.config) must be added to the SQL Binn  directory so that the VS2010 will load frame work 2.x libraries

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```